# Delete and create custom field of an object via APEX

Tags: apex, metadata-api

Is it possible to delete and create custom field of an object  via APEX ? If yes then how?

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain but suspect that the [Apex Metadata API](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_apihttps://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2017/05/introducing-apex-metadata-api) does not include that capability. The common examples of it are to change layouts and manipulate custom metadata records.

That then pushes you into this open source [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) that hasn't been updated for 2 years. I've used it successfully in the past.

Don't invest time in this unless you are really sure your need it. Such code has to be run under a high privilege user and other ways of modifying metadata generally are more appropirate.